# How would I add an action Listener to the button to refresh the image?

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to add an action listener to the "refresh" button but I don't know how I would be able to do this. What I am trying to do is add an action listener so that every time the button is clicked, a new image is taken from the array so the image is replaced with a new one.

```
public class hardMakeupGeneratorTwo extends JFrame{
private ImageIcon image1;
private JLabel label1;
private ImageIcon image2;
private JLabel label2;
private ImageIcon display;
private JButton refresh;

hardMakeupGeneratorTwo (){
    Random rand = new Random();
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("second.jpg"));
    //image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("first.jpg"));
    String[] images = new String[]{"second.jpg", "first.jpg", "IMG_0017.jpg", "IMG_0018.jpg", 
            "IMG_0019.JPG",
            "IMG_0020.JPG",
            "IMG_0021.JPG",
            "IMG_0022.jpg",
            "IMG_0023.jpg",
            "IMG_0024.jpg",
            "IMG_0025.jpg",
            "IMG_0026.jpg",
            "IMG_0027.jpg",
            "IMG_0028.jpg",
            "IMG_0029.jpg",
            "IMG_0030.jpg",
            "IMG_0031.jpg",
            "IMG_0032.jpg",
            "IMG_0033.JPG",
            "IMG_0034.JPG",
            "IMG_0035.JPG",
            "IMG_0036.JPG",
            "IMG_0037.JPG",
            "IMG_0038.JPG",
            "IMG_0039.PNG",
            "IMG_0040.jpg",
            "IMG_0041.JPG",
            "IMG_0042.JPG",
            "IMG_0045.jpg",
            "IMG_0044.jpg",
            "ninth.jpg", 
            "third.jpg", 
            "fourth.jpg", 
            "fifth.jpg",
            "sixth.jpg", 
            "seventh.jpg"};
    int randNum=rand.nextInt(images.length);
    display = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(images[randNum]));
    //image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("first.jpg"));
    label1 = new JLabel(display);
    add(label1);
    refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    add(refresh);
}  

public static void main (String args[]) {
    hardMakeupGeneratorTwo gui = new hardMakeupGeneratorTwo();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.pack();
    gui.setTitle("Here is your look, good luck!");
```

}
}

Comment: Simply call `.setIcon(...)` on the JButton's reference within its listener. Keep a counter int variable and increment it each time the button is pressed.

Comment: Please check out [this search strategy for similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+change+image+with+button+actionlistener+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You also need to read in the images, add a listener to your button,... you may be asking this question a bit early in your attempt

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"you may be asking this question a bit early in your attempt"* Besides that sage advice: work this out with 2 or 3 images, rather than the (counts) **36** referenced above.